# Duvida com foreach C#

Tags: c#

por favor. veja o codigo nesse link: https://pastebin.com/raw/rDCZQhtf
e me diga porque que a frase nao sai com as letra embaralhadas;
se possivel, me da uma ideia de como fazer a mesma coisa com menas linha

---

```
string frase,frase0;
    Console.WriteLine("Digite a frase: ");
    frase0 = Console.ReadLine();
    frase = frase0; 
    foreach(var a in frase0) {
            if(a == 'a'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'g');
            }else if(a == 'b'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'h');
            }else if(a == 'c'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'e');
            }else if(a == 'd'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'j');
            }else if(a == 'e'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'k');
            }else if(a == 'f'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'l');
            }else if(a == 'g'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'm');
            }else if(a == 'h'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'n');
            }else if(a == 'i'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'o');
            }else if(a == 'j'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'p');
            }else if(a == 'k'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'q');
            }else if(a == 'l'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'r');
            }else if(a == 'm'){
                frase.Replace(a, 's');
            }else if(a == 'n'){
                frase.Replace(a, 't');
            }else if(a == 'o'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'u');
            }else if(a == 'p'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'v');
            }else if(a == 'q'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'w');
            }else if(a == 'r'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'x');
            }else if(a == 's'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'y');
            }else if(a == 't'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'z');
            }else if(a == 'u'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'a');
            }else if(a == 'v'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'b');
            }else if(a == 'w'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'c');
            }else if(a == 'x'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'd');
            }else if(a == 'y'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'e');
            }else if(a == 'z'){
                frase.Replace(a, 'f');
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(frase);
```

//essa é só a parte que não esta funcionando

Comment: coloque o código aqui na pergunta por favor

Comment: Use o link **[edit]** para adicionar informações na pergunta. O espaço abaixo que vc usou é somente para respostas. Aproveite para explicar em mais detalhes qual é o problema, o que o código deveria fazer (qual deveria ser o resultado) versus o que ele está fazendo,  etc. Em outras palavras, faça o que chamamos de [mcve]

Comment: Primeiro precisa definir um critério para embaralhar, deve ser aleatório, deve ser só uma troca simples como fez e sempre será assim (o que tecnicamente não é embaralhar). Se fizer o que colocou no código não é embaralhar e não é só linhas demais, é extremamente ineficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que o código abaixo resolve o seu problema com menos linhas, desde que a associação entre as letras seja sempre aquela que indicou na sua questão:

```
string frase0 = string.Empty;
char[] frase = null;
string abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

Console.WriteLine("Digite a frase: ");

frase0 = Console.ReadLine();
frase = frase0.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < frase0.Length; i++)
{
    int index = abc.IndexOf(frase0[i]);
    char newChar = '\0';

    if (frase0[i] == ' ')
        continue;

    if ((index + 6) >= abc.Length)
        newChar = abc[0 + (6 - (abc.Length - index))];
    else newChar = abc[index + 6];

    frase[i] = newChar;
}

Console.WriteLine(new string(frase));
```